# Getting error while connecting to oracle

Tags: oracle11g

Getting following error while connecting to oracle:

```
C:\Users\nikhilgupta>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Jan 19 21:27:54 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name: nikhil
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Please Help.

Comment: Check your oracle database service has been started.

Comment: Thanks suspectus oracle services were closed i started those and it worked.