# connecting nodejs to oracle

Tags: node.js, express, node-oracledb

I installed node-oracle with these instructions: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb

However, I've been beating my head against the wall trying to connect to a remote oracle database.  So I'm tapping into the community to help me out. I have created different *.ora files (ldap.ora, sql.ora TNS etc...) and set my TNS_ADMIN directory to where those files reside.  The bottom line is that I have this connection string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://{hostName-1}:{portNumber}/{dbname},cn=OracleContext,dc=world ldap://{hostName-2}:{portNumber}/{dbname},cn=OracleContext,dc=world
```

I can access the database just fine using Oracle SQL Developer.  However I've had no sucess using SQLPlus or Node.

I've already checked these (among many others):

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3759037

[How do you connect to an LDAP server using node-oracledb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994159/how-do-you-connect-to-an-ldap-server-using-node-oracledb)

[Getting error while connecting to oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219074/getting-error-while-connecting-to-oracle)

[ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error)

Has anyone figured this out yet and can post a solution with the following:

1. your jdbc connection string
2. your sample *.ora files or
   whatever parameter you're passing to oracledb.getConnection() from
   node?

Thanks,

Comment: It might help to give the connection strings you tried in SQL*Plus and the errors you have seen.

Comment: Here's what's in my sqlnet.ora which (AFIK) means to first connect by ldap, then EZ then tns: NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(LDAP, EZCONNECT, TNSNAMES)

The connection strings I've tried in SQLPlus are: 
sqlplus "<username>/<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>"
sqlplus ""<username>/<password>@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=<host>)(Port=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<database>)))"

both of this attempts gave me this error:  ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure
I'm going to search on this now.